# md-switch jumps position on input click

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I'm using Angular-Material's md-switch to style a checkbox, but I'm facing a weird problem.
From standard, the md-switch is using relatively a lot of space in a column, so I wrote some custom css to adjust it to my table cell.

```
md-switch {
    margin: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    line-height: 0px;
} 

md-switch .md-bar {
        background-color: #d0cece; /* set not selected bar color */
}

md-switch.md-checked .md-bar {
        background: rgb(160,209,90); /* Old browsers */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(160,209,90,1) 0%, rgba(117,166,66,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(160,209,90,1) 0%,rgba(117,166,66,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(160,209,90,1) 0%,rgba(117,166,66,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a0d15a', endColorstr='#75a642',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}


md-switch .md-thumb {
        color: rgb(158,158,158); /* not selected switch color */
            line-height: 0px;

}

md-switch.md-checked .md-thumb {
        background: rgb(255,255,255); /* Old browsers */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(234,234,234,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(234,234,234,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(234,234,234,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#eaeaea',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
        border: 1px solid #CBCBCB;

}

md-switch[disabled] .md-thumb {
        background-color: rgb(255,255,255); /* disabled switch color */
}

.md-switch-td {
    margin-top: 0px;
}

md-switch .md-container {
    height: 0px;
}

#md-switch {
    width: 4.3333333%;
}

md-switch[disabled], md-switch[disabled] .md-container {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

at default the md-switch is using:

```
margin: 16px,
line-height: 28px;
height: 30px
```

When entering a page with md-switch on it, the switch is placed out of table cell as shown on this picture:

[image]

When another input is clicked, ex the Description input, the switch jumps back into its intended position:

[image]

I've tried watching the md-switch element in Chrome Developer tool to see if its class changes, when an input is touched, but md-switch's class stays the same:

```
class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid"
```

Anyone who have experienced the same problem or have an idea to a solution?

Thanks in advance!